# Converting an RGB image into a tensor

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision

How to convert and save a collection of different sized images in different forms into a single giant tensor.
I have a directory full of images,around 80000,but not sure on their resolution and format but mostly .jpg and .gif . Now I want to convert them into a giant tensor so that I can place it entirely on the RAM and the training time of the GAN model can be reduced because as of now I am loading the data at run time from the directory so the processing rate of the images are very slow .

Comment: A tensor is regular in terms of dimensions. If you got different dimensions in your images, it won't work. But you can always build a list of arrays/tensors (where each one describes an image). But to be honest: this is basic stuff and all the details (in terms of incorporation into your task) are missing here.

Comment: ok suppose I have images of the same dimentions in the directory  then also How will create the giant tensor with dimension (H,W,3,N) where N : number of samples and 3 : No of channels .

More details :

I have to feed data to a model I am doing right now with feeding from directory approach but its taking too long to  train the model .So thought of feeding numpy array , as of now i am able to create  the big np array  with below code :

Comment: from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import os


def load_image( infilename ) :
    img = Image.open( infilename )
    print ("The size of the Image is: ")
    print(img.format, img.size, img.mode)
    img.load()
    data = np.asarray( img, dtype="int32" )
    return data

path = '/mypath/'

files = os.listdir(path)
image_numpy_array = np.zeros(0)

for images in files:
    print(images)
    out = load_image(path+images)
    image_numpy_array = np.append(image_numpy_array,out)